# Why methanoic acid is more acidic than phenol?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

If you draw the resonatic structure, obviously, the conjugate base of phenol seems to be more stabilized than methanoic acid's. Then why this anomaly?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. Visit the [help] to learn more about how it works.

Comment: Can someone find a duplicate which says that it's **not the number of resonance structures that matters, but rather the extent of their contribution**? This question has been asked too many times.

Comment: ``obviously, the conjugate base of phenol seems to be more stabilized than methanoic acid's`` No, I do not think this is obvious at all. As @orthocresol pointed out, the number of resonance structures is of secondary importance compared to their individual stability and contribution.